# Two different 3-AND gates: correct implementation?

Tags: transistors, logic-gates

One of the questions in my textbook ([*Introduction to Computing Systems*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0072467509)) asks to design a 3-input AND gate. The given solution is as follows:

[image: Given 3-AND gate solution]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTPJ6P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If I am reading this correctly, this is a 3-NAND–NOT combination.
I don't understand why you need the NAND–NOT instead of just creating an AND by itself.
My proposed schematic is the following:

[image: My proposed 3-AND gate]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9t2Sf.png)</sup>

This seems simpler, and uses fewer transistors, so I'm guessing that there's some reason that it won't work (otherwise it would be the example solution!).
I don't see any possibilities for short-circuiting: if `NAND(A,B,C)`, then `NOT OUT`, so there will be no path from power to ground (because it would have to go through `OUT`).
On the other hand, I do think that everything is properly grounded: if `NAND(A,B,C)`, then `OUT` should have a path to ground through whichever of `(A,B,C)` is logically false.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to use the schematic editor. If someone wants to replace my images, please feel free!

Comment: You're missing how MOSFETs work and what the gate voltage (Vgs) has to be.

Comment: Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/143811/cmos-or-gate-using-4-transistors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're misunderstanding (or not having the basic understanding) of how MOSFETs work, in particular the \$V_{GS}\$.

On an N-channel MOSFET the gate voltage has to rise a certain amount above the source pin.  On a P-channel it has to fall a certain amount below the source pin.

In your schematic the N-channel's source is connected to \$V_{CC}\$ and the P-channel's to GND.  If the threshold is, say, 1.2V (a reasonable logic level threshold), then the input logic HIGH would have to be at least 1.2V above \$V_{CC}\$ and the logic LOW would have to be below -1.2V.

That, as you can see, just isn't practical.

Comment: You're certainly right that I don't understand how these work `:)` Is $V_{CC}$ just the battery/power voltage? (The bar at the top of my hand-drawn schematic?) And what is $V_{GS}$?

Comment: Hmm...so is the key that the gate voltage is compared *relative* to the source voltage, as opposed to, say, \$0\,\mathrm{V}\$? In that case, would it *ever* make sense to connect an N-type transistor to power or a P-type transistor to ground?

Comment: There are times when you would do that, but you generally require a special driving circuit.  In normal logic it's never used like that.

Comment: \$V_{GS}\$ is the difference in voltage between the gate and the source pins.  \$V_{CC}\$ is the supply voltage (battery voltage).

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! You've certainly given me some things to think about.