# CMOS 2-input OR logic gate Circuit (using 4 MOSFET transistors)

Tags: logic-gates, cmos, circuits

I've been trying to find the way to create an OR Logic gate circuit but I can't seem to find anything online. Is there a way to do it with 6 transistors instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMOS OR gate using 4 Transistors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/143811/cmos-or-gate-using-4-transistors)

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Use 4 transistors to create a NOR gate, then another two to invert the output.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to create one using only 4 transistors?

Comment: @EmmaJohnson I don't think so. You need 4 transistors to build the NOR, and an inverter is already optimized with 2 transistors. But I'm not an expert. -- Did you check the Wikipedia pages? They often include valuable links.

Answer (score -3):

To make a basic model of an OR-gate you can just swap a NMOS and a PMOS in a NOR-gate. This gate gives us less than unity voltage gain, but it does't matter if there is any NOT/NOR/NAND gates right after this OR-gate.

In fact, this is all convention. For example, an adder can only be done with AND/OR/NOT gates. But you will use far fewer transistors if you use the XOR gate. Or you can make a logic multiplexer with solid-state relays, which cannot be done with discrete MOS, but these relays are easy enough to build on silicon.

[image]

Comment: No, you can't just swap NMOS and PMOS -- that gives you a gate that has less than unity voltage gain, which cannot be used to build larger circuits. Note also that the gate you created is AND, not OR.